# MySQL query for distance and using AND in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, distance

I need help of the experts here with MySQL query. I have latitudes and longitudes in MySQL database. I am able to get the nearest locations from the query but the moment I try to add "AND" to the query, I get an error.

I have done lot of research but could not find an answer.

- `$lat_database` is the user's requested latitude
- `$lon_database` is the user's requested longitude
- `latitude` - latitude column name in MySQL database
- `longitude` - longitude column name in MySQL database

```
SELECT *,
       ((ACOS(SIN($lat_database * PI() / 180)
            * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180)
            + COS($lat_database * PI() / 180)
            * COS(latitude * PI() / 180)
            * COS(($lon_database - longitude) * PI() / 180)
             ) * 180 / PI()
        ) * 60 * 1.1515
       ) as distance
HAVING distance <= 20
   AND items LIKE ('%" . $item . "%')
FROM items
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

Comment: Your query has two `FROM` clauses, this is not allowed in SQL. What are you trying to do? Sample data and expected results would help.

Comment: ah sorry! I was playing around with the query so had two FROM's. Here is the query:$sql = "SELECT *, 
((ACOS(SIN($lat_database * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + 
COS($lat_database * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * 
COS(($lon_database - longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) 
as distance HAVING distance <= 20 
AND items LIKE ('%" . $item . "%') FROM items ORDER BY distance ASC $limit";

Comment: I am trying to find all items within 20 miles using the user given location.

Comment: Having clause comes after the from, not before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use join and after use where

```
$sql = "SELECT *, ((ACOS(SIN($lat_database * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + COS($lat_database * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * 
COS(($lon_database - longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) 
as distance FROM locations
join items on items.id = t1.item_id
where item LIKE ('%" . $item . "%')
 HAVING distance <= 20 
 ORDER BY distance ASC $limit";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Hossein! How would I count all the records (SELECT COUNT (unique_id)) that the query above is returning?

Comment: inject sql code to this code ```select count(q1.unique_id) from ($sql) as q1```